# Notify Birthdays while pc starts in window application using c#

Tags: c#-4.0

I am developing an windows application in which I want birthdays reminder of the clients. So what I want is, when my pc starts, a program file should run automatically(i.e without click on the icon of setup) and fetch the records from database and show it to notify icon.
If you hae any idea regarding this please tell the flow.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you've listed a few steps - which one is causing problems? Are you able to run a program on startup? If not, that's the first place to start. If you can, then it's irrelevant to the rest of your problem. You need to ask a *specific* question, basically.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jon.
Actually I have tried it by using windows service. but don't know how to execute the window service without opening the application. I want to show notification at the bottom right corner when my pc starts, not by opening the specific application.